# How do i switch screens from one file to another

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator, react-navigation-stack

I'm very new to react native so please explain carefully.i have 3 files ***App.js*** ***SplashAndLogin.js*** and ***Register.js*** Im able to get from the initial screen to the register screen and go back and forth between my components in my Register file but when its time to go back to the Login screen i always seem to get the same error.

I've tried several different things but they all keep giving me the same error. im starting to think the way i set up my files are just wrong.

```
//App.js


 class App extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
       return (
     <AppContainer/>
    )
  }
}
export default App

const AppSwitchNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Login: {screen: SplashAndLogin},
    //Registe :{screen: Register}
  });


//SplashAndLogin.js

class SplashAndLogin extends Component<Props> {
  render() {
       return (
     <AppContainer/>
    )
  }
}

export default SplashAndLogin;

const SAndLAppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    SandL : {screen: LoadingScreen },
    RegisterScreen : {screen: Register} 
  }
);


//Register.js

export default class Application extends Component<Props> {
    render() {
         return (
        <AppContainer/>
       );
    }
  }

  const AppSwitchNavigator = createStackNavigator(
    {
      Login :{screen: NameScreen},
      PhoneAndEmail: {screen: EmailPasswordScreen},
      HomeScreen: {screen: SplashAndLogin },
      UploadScreen: {screen: CertificateUploadScreen }


    });

  const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppSwitchNavigator);
```

So to summarize i can get to every screen except when im on the Register.js file and try to navigate to the ***HomeScreen*** it throws out the error

"The component for route 'HomeScreen' must be a react component For example...."

Comment: Something's wrong with your navigation system.

Comment: Any tips on how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

It's normal, you are using two different AppContainer.

You can not call a view in another AppContainer from the current AppContainer

```
this.props.navigation
```

refers to the current navigation

Answer (score 0):

Use the state to change AppContainer

```
class RenderAppContainer extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { IsConnected : false } 
        this.changeIsConnected = this.changeIsConnected.bind(this)
    }

    changeIsConnected = () => { 
      this.setState((prevState, props ) => ({ IsConnected : !prevState.IsConnected}))
    } 

    render() {
         cons {IsConnected } = this.state 

         return(
           <React.Fragment>
            {(IsConnected) ? AppContainerOne : AppContainerTwo } 
           </React.Fragment
         )
    }

}
```

You can then pass changeIsConnected to your AppContainer

```
<AppContainerOne screenProps={{changeConnected: this.changeIsConnected}} />
<AppContainerTwo screenProps={{changeConnected: this.changeIsConnected}} />
```

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html

see documentation for ScreenProps